# What is the alternative for WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

**What is the alternative for the below code snippet in .NET Core?**

```
WebOperationContext webContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
webContext.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are looking for alternate snippet?

Comment: @Chetan I'm trying to port it to .NET Core.